# WIX setup perUser or perMachine depends from current user

Tags: wix

I'm new in WIX. I neet to set **Installscope** to **perUser** if current user is in local admin groups (not runAsAdmin) or **perMachine** otherwise
I know about **ALLUSERS="2"** and **MSIINSTALLPERUSER="1|{}"**, but I can't to set them dynamically BEFORE wix decide how it will be runned - as perUser or perMachine
I used CustomAction to detect if current user is in Administrators group and to set **ALLUSERS** and **MSIINSTALLPERUSER**, put in in InstallExecuteSequence, but this action always runs AFTER wix decision
How can I implement dynamically set this properties of InstallScope depend by current user and admin group?
My sample WIX

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="rrr" UpgradeCode="3664d946-e6b5-468f-8154-0506308d85ab">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"  >
    </Package>

    <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.CustomAction1.TargetDir)$(var.CustomAction1.TargetName).CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="SampleAction" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='SampleAction' Before='SetProps'/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Inside **SetProps** ALLUSERS and MSIINSTALLPERUSER are set to 2 and 1
But installer is run with UAC call (due to **perMachine**)

Answer (score 0):

The question is closed.
I use **Custom Action** in InstallUISequence.